# EasyPeasy (NSLayoutConstraint) doesnot change custom view frame if device is rotated

Tags: ios, swift

This code creates my custom view using EasyPeasy library

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    chart = Init( ChartView(frame: .zero, with: calc)) {) {
                        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                }
                view.addSubview(chart)
                chart <- [
                    Top(0).to(self.topLayoutGuide),
                    Bottom(0),
                    Left(0),
                    Right(0)
                ]

                chart.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

But  if I rotate a device my custom view is not reloaded: it just  incorrectly scaled (e.g., circles into ovals). But if I manually redraw using `chart.layoutIfNeeded()` it works fine.
Is there any way to say: "please, dear device, redraw my custom view each time I change frame / rotate of my view"?
P.S. EasyPeasy uses `NSLayoutConstraint`. 
https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solves my problem:

```
chart = Init( ChartView(frame: .zero, with: calc)) {
                    $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    $0.contentMode = .redraw
            }
```

I mean view wants this method: `setNeedsDisplay()`. To do it automatically by OS it is needed to set `chart.contentMode = .redraw` .